# MySQL connector PreparedStatement->setString not working C++

Tags: c++, string, mysql-connector

So, basically all this code does is search the database for a user with a certain username and password, and returns a nullptr if it doesn't find one.

```cpp
    Gebruiker* Gebruiker_DAO::getGebruiker(string login, string wachtwoord)
{

    PreparedStatement *prep_stmt = nullptr;
    ResultSet *res = nullptr;
    Gebruiker* gebruiker = nullptr;
    int rowcount = 0;

    try {
        prep_stmt = dbConn->getConnection()->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Gebruiker WHERE Gebruiker_login = ? AND Gebruiker_wachtwoord = ?");

        prep_stmt->setString(1, login);
        prep_stmt->setString(2, wachtwoord);

        res = prep_stmt->executeQuery();
        while (res->next()) {
            gebruiker = new Gebruiker(login, res->getBoolean("Gebruiker_isAdmin"), res->getString("Bedrijf"),res->getBoolean("Gebruiker_isActief"),res->getInt("Werknemer_ID"));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException& e) {
        console.log(e.what(), console.Error);
        return nullptr;
    }

    return gebruiker;
}
```

The issue is that setString throws an "std::bad_alloc at memory location ..."
Ive noticed before that trying to put a string in an SQLString also throws an error. Until now ive used a workaround by putting stuff in SQLStrings.

```
SQLString schema = "groep003B";
    dbConn->getInstance()->setSchema(schema);
    dbConn->getInstance()->connect();
```

For some weird reason this DOES work...

Is there something i am doing wrong? I have seen examples where people use strings, but for some reason this does not work for me... Every time i try to put a variable std::string in an SQLString it gives a memory issue.

Comment: Compile the connector from source. I've had the same issue with the precompiled library.

Comment: Ok, thanks ill try that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Apparently the library only accepts cstrings. So, adding .c_str() after "login" and "wachtwoord" did the trick. Pretty weird that it doesnt accept strings. Maybe its because i use an older version of the lib...